# convert large integer to float in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

an API that I cannot influence is saving certain floating point numbers as contiguousarray with 64 bit, so that a value of -0.30273306 is saved as -4624246862885421056.

Now how can I retrieve the original value from this large integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module. Firstly we pack `i` as long long (8 bytes signed integer). Then we unpack it as double (8-byte floating point number).

```
import struct

i = -4624246862885421056
f = struct.unpack("d", struct.pack("q", i))
```

Comment: that looks cumbersome but thanks a lot =) does this also work for numpy arrays or just for single numbers?

Comment: @CarstenD, that's best option in my opinion. If you're reading this values from file, you can read them as double. About numpy arrays I don't clearly understand.

Comment: how would I read the data as double? several of those numbers are stored as meta data in an hdf5 file and I need to access it by a key that returns an np.array which contains multiple numbers

Comment: @CarstenD, it's much more complicated question. I'm not familiar with this file format, so I can't help you using my own experience. If in codec you use to read this file there's some option to override reader, you can use it.

Comment: @CarstenD, about numpy array, I think there's an option how to apply same changes to all elements.